# AJAX function needed (toggle text)

Tags: ajax

I am looking for a function that will toggle text exactly as shown by pressing the "Phone" button on [this website](http://www.superyachts.com/luxury-yacht-for-sale/agatha-1371/).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ ...also your question would be better served over at [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) as this relates to JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you need any AJAX here, You can do this also using jQuery Slide method.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Try here

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_down

Comment: i think there is a conflict with my other plugins and nothing happens when i click the text.. is there any way i can modify this with no-conflict mode?